# Obtain an equal length data frame that starts after the last row with NAs column

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a 400 similar length columns with different lengths of `NA`s at the beginning of columns - How could I obtain an equal row length data frame that begins after the last row with `NA`s from any column.

```
X<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,3,4,5,67,8,9,2)
Y<-c(NA,NA,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,8,9)
s<-data.frame(X,Y)

s
    X  Y
1  NA NA
2  NA NA
3  NA  2
4  NA  3
5   3  4
6   4  1
7   5  5
8  67  6
9   8  7
10  9  8
11  2  9
```

Desired output:

```
    X  Y
1   3  4
2   4  1
3   5  5
4  67  6
5   8  7
6   9  8
7   2  9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t <- na.omit(s); 
rownames(t) <- NULL
```

This will re-index so it exactly matches your example (not clear if you were concerned about the indices).

Answer (score 2):

what about `na.omit()`?

```
> na.omit(s)
    X Y
5   3 4
6   4 1
7   5 5
8  67 6
9   8 7
10  9 8
11  2 9
```